# SAPUI5 - Uncaught TypeError: this.getRouter.navTo is not a function

Tags: sapui5

I am referring to the code used in tdg master-detail demokit application.

I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: this.getRouter.navTo is not a function".

I have written a `console.log("is router fine? "+ this.getRouter().toLocaleString());` before this.getRouter.navTo which prints as 
"**EventProvider company.accounts_positions_splitpage.MyRouter**"

Any suggestions what is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: are you calling `this.getRouter.navTo` or `this.getRouter().navTo` the first tries to call `navTo` on the function, the second calls it on the received router

Comment: Wow!! I am using `this.getRouter.navTo`. To my understanding, the call should invoke sap.ui.core.routing.Router's method, which was failing. Can you reply to this question instead of comment. I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call

```
this.getRouter().navTo()
```

instead of

```
this.getRouter.navTo()
```

With `this.getRouter` you do not execute the function, you just get the function as Object. There you try too execute the function `navTo()`, but that object itselve does not provide such a function.

With `this.getRouter()` you execute the function and you get the return value (a router) as Object. On that router you can now use `navTo()`, as you did in your `console.log`.